# Getting WebpackOptionsValidationError on upgrading packaje.json entries

Tags: angular, webpack

I updated the angular libraries and webpack in package.json manually. Now when I run the application I get following error:

```
System.Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.
    at webpack (C:\FoodPortal.Intertek.Project\FoodPortal.Intertek\FoodPortal.Intertek\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:19:9)
    at attachWebpackDevMiddleware (C:\FoodPortal.Intertek.Project\FoodPortal.Intertek\FoodPortal.Intertek\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:66:20)
    at C:\FoodPortal.Intertek.Project\FoodPortal.Intertek\FoodPortal.Intertek\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:217:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\FoodPortal.Intertek.Project\FoodPortal.Intertek\FoodPortal.Intertek\node_modules\aspnet-webpack\WebpackDevMiddleware.js:192:32)
    at Server.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at emitListeningNT (net.js:1285:10)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:71:11)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using an empty string in [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions) which is no longer allowed or needed in webpack 2.

Instead of having:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
}
```

You just need:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.json']
}
```

There will be other breaking changes you need to fix when upgrading to webpack 2. Read the official [Migration Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/) to see what you need to change.